# Does the Staff of Defense count as an arcane focus?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, dnd-adventurers-league

I thought the Staff of Defense from the start set should count as an arcane focus, but a few people have disagreed with me.  I'm wondering if there's any explicit information out there, because most of what I've found seems to be disagreements.

Preferred answers will include a reference that will hold up in Adventure League games.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Does every magic rod, wand, crystal, orb, and staff count as an arcane focus?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59951)

Answer (score 10):

Does it say in the description: "may be used as an arcane focus"? No? Then no.

Comment: Actually, there is all of ONE item in the entire DMG that states 'may be used as an arcane focus', and that's a spellbook.  Given that it includes an entire raft of wands, staves, and rods intended to help spellcasters, I'd argue that the very failure to specify that ability in _any_ of them implies that they _can_ all be used as arcane foci.  Otherwise things like the wand of the war mage make no sense -- 'I cast spells more powerful using this wand, but I have to have a second wand as my arcane focus!' makes _no_ sense.