# If I use a quarterstaff as my Arcane Focus, can I add my Proficiency Bonus, the way a Bard does when using an instrument as their arcane focus?

Tags: dnd-5e, proficiency, spellcasting-focus

A Bard can add their Proficiency Bonus to checks they make with a *Musical Instrument* they're proficient with. It says on p.154 under ***Musical Instruments*** in the *Player's Handbook:*

> If you have proficiency with a Musical Instrument you can add the proficiency for what ever you do with it. A bard can use a musical instrument as a spellcasting focus,...

I wonder, can I do the equivalent as a Wizard, with an *Arcane Focus (staff)* doubled as a Quarterstaff?

Related Question: [Is it possible to use a weapon as a normal weapon and an arcane focus at the same time?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128856/is-it-possible-to-use-a-weapon-as-a-normal-weapon-and-an-arcane-focus-at-the-sam)

Comment: I meant adding it to rolls...

Comment: To put it another way... What makes you think a bard is special or different from any other spellcaster?

Comment: I guess the OP means attacking with Quarterstaff and adding proficiency bonus to the attack roll.

Comment: I cleaned up some formatting to help readability, note that "preformatted" formatting is only really suited to code, for quoting normal text we much prefer blockquotes (>). Speaking of quotes, the quote you give doesn't exactly match the one in my book, so if you're translating or sourcing from something other than a book it might be useful to state what your source is.

Comment: Is this question about tool proficiencies? Because arcane focuses are not tools, which may be why so many people are confused about the question.

Comment: Please don't edit your solution into the question. Once the question is reopened you can answer it yourself with the reasons you came up with.

Answer (score 5):

### Your proficiency bonus is already applied to spell save DCs and spell attacks

The Basic Rules clarify, in the [chapter on Spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#AttackRolls) (**emphasis** mine):

> The DC to resist one of your spells equals 8 + your spellcasting ability modifier **+ your proficiency bonus** + any special modifiers.

and...

> Your attack bonus with a spell attack equals your spellcasting ability modifier **+ your proficiency bonus**.

---

Using a spellcasting focus only replaces certain material components...

> A character can use a **component pouch** or a **spellcasting focus** in place of the components specified for a spell.

...so being proficient with an arcane focus has no affect on the details of spellcasting.

As an additional note, this is true not only for arcane foci that double as quarterstaffs, but also for such characters as bards of the College of Swords who gain:

> If you’re proficient with a simple or martial melee weapon, you can use it as a spellcasting focus for your bard spells.

Comment: It's not true that you *always* use your proficiency bonus when casting spells. Notable exceptions are *counterspell* and *dispel magic*.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson Fair enough. Title fixed