# What rarity should this homebrew scimitar fused to a wand of the war mage be?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons, homebrew-review

I made a weapon in D&D 5e: A silver-plated scimitar that has a [*+2 wand of the war mage*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/wand-of-the-war-mage) fused along the back of the blade, and an Arcane Focus crystal embedded in the hilt.

I also placed a [*continual flame*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/continual-flame) evocation spell on the crossguard, making it appear as if flames danced on the crossguard.  It acts as a torch in terms of utility but does not need oxygen and does not burn anything.

What rarity should it be? Common, Uncommon, Rare, Very Rare, or legendary?

Comment: Related on [Does every magic rod/wand/crystal orb/staff count as an arcane focus?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59951/does-every-magic-rod-wand-crystal-orb-and-staff-count-as-an-arcane-focus)

Comment: FYI, you can't choose what part of the object gets the *continual flame*. The whole object gets it.

Comment: um, I see a lot of proper form like in d&d DMG for home-brew stuff on this site, where are those coming from?

Comment: @EvokerofMulmaster: Do you mean the formatting? That's usually just edited by fellow users or the authors themselves to look nicer and/or for consistency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Rare

The primary actor in this item is the Wand itself, which as you've linked is a Rare item due to the +2 modifiers.

While the other parts add some utility, there really isn't anything that's going to push the rarity up another level.

The silvered scimitar makes this wand a weapon as well. While that improves the utility of it, I don't think it's a real issue. The scimitar doesn't benefit from the +2 because the Wand is specific in how it works, so the only real benefit here is the melee option and the silvered property. On the flipside, it's now part metal and someone casting *heat metal* on it would be a problem for you

The arcane focus covers your bases to make sure it's an arcane focus, but again, that's not a big deal.

Finally, the *continual flame* is a neat touch, but doesn't offer anything that's going to upgrade it's rarity. In fact, it may create more problems than it will solve. You've got a continuous undousable light source on your weapon now. Fighting in dark environments where stealth is key may create a problem for you and your party.

Comment: intreting, although I can dispel this flame at any time.

Comment: @EvokerofMulmaster: If that's an intended aspect of the *continual flame* effect, you should include that information in the question. (That is, if it works differently from the spell itself, which can be dispelled only with *dispel magic* or a similar spell.)

Comment: OK, I appreciate that