# Does Amulet of the Devout give bonuses to spells that aren't paladin or sorcerer spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, multi-classing

The Amulet of the Devout requires attunement by a Cleric or Paladin, and provides the following benefit:

> This amulet bears the symbol of a deity inlaid with precious stones or metals. While you wear the holy symbol, you gain a +1 bonus to spell attack rolls and the saving throw DCs of your spells.

Suppose I have a multiclassed character that can attune to the amulet, such as a Paladin / Sorcerer. Does the bonus of the amulet apply to all my spells, or only to my Cleric & Paladin spells?

Comment: Somewhat related: "[How does the Wand of the War Mage work for a multiclassed warlock/sorcerer?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152623)"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### All your spells gain the +1 bonuses

The item states:

> While you wear the holy symbol, you gain a +1 bonus to spell attack rolls and the saving throw DCs of your spells.

It does not restrict this bonus to a certain class of spells; it does not say "your paladin spells" or "your cleric spells" but simply says "your spells" and because of this, it applies to *all* of your spells, no matter what class they come from.

---

Two examples of items that *do* have restrictions based on class are the Rod of the Pact Keeper or the Book of Exalted Deeds:

> While holding this rod, you gain a +1 bonus to spell attack rolls and to the saving throw DCs of your warlock spells. [...]

> [...] any spell slot you expend to cast a cleric or paladin spell counts as a spell slot of one level higher. [...]

The Amulet of the Devout does not use wording similar to these items and so it does not have the same sort of restriction; it benefits *all* of your spells.