# Does the Magic Initiate feat require another focus?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, spellcasting, spellcasting-focus

Put simply, if say a druid wanted to take the [Magic Initiate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/magic-initiate) feat to gain access to sorcerer spells, would that require them to have a component pouch or arcane focus to cast those spells, as it would with a multiclass? Or will their own druidic focus work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Another focus will not work (and your own focus only if you pick spells from your class)

For example, the druid class says (page 66 PHB)

> You can use a druidic focus (found in chapter 5) as a
> spellcasting focus **for your druid spells**.

It is similar for the other classes, each has a feature that allows them to use a focus *for their class's spells*. So, you can only use your focus for your own classes spells - as a druid, you can only use it for druid spells, not for the spells Magic Initiate grants (unless they are druid spells).

Magic Initiate says:

> Choose a class: bard, cleric, druid, sorcerer, warlock, or wizard. You learn two cantrips of your choice from that class's spell list. In addition, choose one 1st-level spell to learn from that same list.

Magic Initiate does not grant you the full spellcasting features of the class you pick the spells from. In particular, it does not give you the "Spellcasting Focus" feature that would allow you to use a focus to cast spells of that class.

If you pick cantrips and a spell from your native class's list, you can use your own focus. For example, if you are a druid, and pick druid cantrips and spell, because they are druid spells, you will be able to use your focus (and also [your normal spell slots](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68451/can-you-cast-a-spell-learned-from-the-magic-initiate-feat-using-spell-slots)).

If you however pick spells from another class, you have no feature that allows you to use a focus for them. You would need the components, or a component pouch to cast those spells.

Answer (score 4):

### A component pouch will work for you.

The [component pouch](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/component-pouch) contains all the (costless) material components you will ever need for any spell from any class.

But if you come across a [Wand of the War Mage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/34712-wand-of-the-war-mage), you can not use it as a druidic focus, as discussed [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/152625/75422). You may still be able to benefit from the bonus though.

Comment: What do you mean by +1 wand?

Comment: @Eddymage Good remark, I added link to the item I had in mind

Comment: @EternalCrow the description of the wand that's linked does not imply a need to use the wand as a spellcasting focus to get the bonus. You simply need to be attuned to it and hold it while casting.

Comment: @Matthieu You are right, I will rephrase my last sentence.

Comment: Actually, neither a Wand of the War Mage can be used as a spellcasting focus: see [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/201289/63061)  and [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/59952/63061).